# Authenticating Google users without registering application first

Tags: google-oauth

The old Google OpenID endpoint provided a way of authenticating users without having to register your application first. This was very convenient for open source applications because they could provide a "log in with Google" option which would work out of the box. For instance, Google's own code review tool Gerrit makes use of this.

It appears that this endpoint is deprecated and will be shutdown:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OpenID2

My question is twofold:

1. Is the endpoint that's going to be shutdown the one at https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id used by StackOverflow, Gerrit etc.? (With all the different OAuth and OpenID variants mentioned in Google's docs, it's not terribly clear.)
2. If so, is there any non-deprecated login option that doesn't require the application to be registered.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration#timetable Looks to me like they are shutting it down soon.  As far as I know everything requires that you register it in the cloud console.   You can still release it with your client_id, client_secret,  if it gets locked out delete it make a new one. Anyone that's still running the old one will be forced to make there own.   With my sample projects I have things set with dummy ids, with a note in the sample if you see this go make your own app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed OpenID2 is deprecated, and that is the endpoint at  https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id;

Open-Source code can still be written; it will require just that the site integrating the open-source solution perform the registration step and supply the registration values (client_id, redirect_uri) to the open-source code. If you write the code with a modular approach to configuring the registration data, the code can be highly re-usable.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, absolutely it's still possible to use in open-source software. It's just a shame that you can't get the same out-of-the-box, plug-and-play experience. Ah well!